# Give an example of two uncountable sets A and B such that A − B is

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Give an example of two uncountable sets A and B such
that A − B is

a) ﬁnite.

b) countably inﬁnite.

Answer (score 1):

$a$) $A=\mathbb{R}$, $B = \mathbb{R} \backslash \{1\}$.

$b$) $A = \mathbb{R}$, $B = \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{N}$.

In both cases, the strategy is as follows. Pick any uncountable set to be $A$. To now choose $B$, pick a finite or countably infinite set and subtract it from $A$ to get $B$.

Comment: @DonLarynx ????

Answer (score 0):

$\scr{R} - \scr{R}$ is certainly finite.

$\scr{R} - \scr{I}$ where $\scr{I}$ is the set of irrationals satisfies $b$.